# ASP.Net Roles: Page-Level Security Question

Tags: asp.net, security

We're currently in the process of re-creating a brand new security model that dwarfs our existing process. Right now, we plan on grabbing a user's roles during the login process and then using a Base Page class to check if the user has the role of the corresponding page the user is navigating to.

We can limit the menu's options by the user's roles as well, but we have had problems with users navigating to pages in our system by typing them in or having old bookmarks. Obviously, we need some sort of page level access.

A simple function in our Base Page class that checks the role in the Arraylist against the page's assigned role would work, but I was wondering if there was any built-in functionality to support this or a cleaner solution possibly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using built-in membership?

If so, you can use the `location` section of your `web.config` file to restrict access to individual pages or entire directories. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx):

> The following example allows an
>   anonymous user to access the
>   Logon.aspx page:

```
<configuration>
   <location path="Logon.aspx">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The problem is that this is based on every user. There are roughly 10,000+ users, and each may or may not have a completely different set of rules. Adding all those distinctions into the web.config seems like a rather large and lengthy task.

Comment: @jlrolin - you can use `<allow roles="Admins"/>` or similar as well

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at ASP.Net Membership for this yet?  It takes care of all of the scenarios you listed above (trimming menus, page security,) and in a very easy to use manner.

See here for more information about membership - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx.

Comment: I suppose rolling our own role provider and calling a User.IsInRole function of the role on the page would suffice if I was referencing the session'ed Arraylist of Roles that the user has. That'd basically be the same thing as calling a Base Page class function.

Comment: If you were to use the Membership RoleProvider along with the Location/Authorization section of your web config to specify which roles can see which pages, you shouldn't have to ever reference your list of roles from the page.