# Validating user role's page level access

Tags: c#, asp.net

My question is almost similar to this 
[ASP.Net Roles: Page-Level Security Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804572/asp-net-roles-page-level-security-question)
except for the fact that I'm not using asp.net membership, What I have done is I have created roles and assigned pages to roles, menus are also populating according to the user's role. I want to restrict user to access pages by simply typing the `PageName.aspx` , One solution might be checking on every page load, but I don't think it's efficient. I have googled but only found solutions for adding `<location path="Logon.aspx">` to restrict, I have to add this for every page in `web.config`, which defeats the whole purpose of keeping this thing dynamic, I am **using Form Authentication**, Some are suggesting creating a **Base Class** and derive other pages from that class, I think there may be some `global.asax` way to acheive this, but have no idea. Please suggest me best approach to achieve this !

P.S : I am **not using ASP.NET Membership**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally, what I did is I checked access of Pages for every user on MasterPage's `Page_Load` using a method name `IsPageAssignedToRole()` to check

```
        string requestedPage = Request.Url.Segments[Request.Url.Segments.Length-1];
        if (requestedPage != "UnAuthorized.aspx")
        {
        AdminUserAuthInfo au = (AdminUserAuthInfo)Context.Items["AdminUserAuthInfo"];
        int current_role= int.Parse(au.Roles[0].ToString());
        if (!AdminRole.IsPageAssignedToRole(current_role, requestedPage))
        { Response.Redirect("UnAuthorized.aspx",true); }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

legendinmaking,

This is depend on your project layout . One solution is that you create a folder structure where you place *webconfig* and there you give permission for the user i think this may be one solution and may be others.

Comment: Thanx for your help but I don't want to add role level access for every page to be defined in web.config, I am keeping this role-base-page level access dynamic.

Comment: another options is that you create permission in table when anyone try to open the page then that will be check is there page is can view by that user true or false then the page will open.. any question you can discuss again

Comment: that's what I am asking ! I have that information in database but how can I call the checking method on every page load ? I don't think writing that on every page load is recommended

Comment: i think you need to use that on page init you first check user and its permission i think that is only one solution i think according me .